# C Memory management with int pointer (array)?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, free

Simple question, but the other similar questions on here are don't deal with this specific case, or so i could find.

```
int * moves;
moves = malloc(540); //540 is the most i will ever need, usually less
someFunctionThatFillsSomeOfThoseSlots // also returns how many slots were used

int * final = malloc(size+1);

for(x = 0; x < size; x++, final++, moves++)
    final = moves;
final -= size;
```

how should i be freeing the memory of moves, after having changed its pointer?

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: If you change `moves` without `free`ing its memory, that's a memory leak. From the given code, though, it looks like the memory you allocated to `final` is wasted.

Comment: Should i make another pointer to the begining of moves, chage that new pointer, and then free(moves)? i know it is a memory leak how it is now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
final = moves;
```

reassigns the variable `final` to `moves`, so the just allocated pointer is lost in the universe of leaked memory.

What you probably meant is:

```
*final = *moves;
```

which assigns to the location pointed by `final`, the value pointed by `moves`.

But this doesn't solve your problem, since if you lose the address that malloc gave initially for `moves` you can't `free` it. You could do `free(moves - size)` but it's just complicated.

Why don't you just use `[]` operator?

```
for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
  final[x] = moves[x];
```

Comment: I'm converting a ChessAI from java to C in an attempt to make it faster. I was under the impression that iterating over the points was faster than doing it with [].

Comment: To be under the impression of something is meaningless when developing software. The only meaningful thing is to verify if something is really a bottleneck, measure it and then draw conclusions. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding

Comment: i am now using the [] operator and my program is now crashing

Comment: The issue was     malloc(size+1)  was allocating one forth the memory i needed because they are all ints

Comment: @Toolbox97 using the pattern `p = calloc(N, sizeof *p);` or `p = malloc(N * sizeof *p);` avoids that sort of problem